# Classloader issue on Mule server

Tags: spring, mule, spring-batch, mule-studio

I am running my application on **mule server**. Mule server has there own sets of jars and my application that is running on mule server also has few jars. While working on Spring batch I found that `JettisonMappedXmlDriver` class exists in my application `xstream jar` as well as `mule server jar` as well. This class internally refer `MappedXMLOutputFactory` class that is in `jettision jar` which is also in my application but some how I am getting **classnotfound error** for `MappedXMLOutputFactory` class. This looks like **class-loader issue.**

If I add `jettision jar` in mule server then everything work fine but, I can't add this jar on my production environment. Can some body tell me how do I force to load the class from my application `jettision jar` file. It looks weird to me as *classloader* should have load `MappedXMLOutputFactory` class from `jettision jar` that is in my application folder like it is doing for other classes.
Please let me know if anybody found such issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Mule application classloader is configurable: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule

So just configure your application's classloader to first look at the JARs it embeds in `/lib` before deferring to the Mule System classloader.

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter this issue if you have multiple versions of the same class in differnet jars, albeit with different method signatures. The ClassNotFound Error is usually not the only exception that occurs, you will often see another one before that, typically a "NoSuchMethodException" which forces class loader to unload the offending class.

I would suggest using maven or gradle to assemble your application and then use the dependency:tree target to query version conflicts.